# PCIE root complex failover

Tags: pci-express

PCIE switches from Avago and IDT have the capability of root complex failover.

This sureley does not happen over an instant - there must be some time that elapses before the secondary root complex detects that the active root complex has failed and establishes itself as the root complex. Lets call this the failover period.

My question is - what happens to the end point devices at this point. My endpoint devices do not have any frequent communication with root complex devices - only between themselves over the PCIE network. Will the end to end PCIE communication be unavailable during this failover?

Answer (score 4):

Q: Will the end to end PCIE communication be unavailable during this failover?

A: Most probably there will be slight delay in service. Contact hardware vendor for particular device implementation details.

Comment: Thanks @BaronSamedi1958. During thing delay will the end point device be able to communicate with each other - or will the communication result in reporting a failure to the application?